# Capture stdout and stderr as separate variables in fish shell

Tags: command-substitution, stderr, fish

Is this even possible?

I'd like to run a command but capture its stdout and stderr as separate variables. Currently I'm using `set -l var (cmd)`, which leaves stderr untouched. I can do `set -l var (cmd ^&1)` which will merge stdout and stderr into var, but then I can't easily separate them again.

Is there any way to get var and var_err to hold stdout and stderr from cmd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
begin; cmd ^|read -z err; end |read -z out
```

From [fish-shell/fish-shell #2463](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2463),

> An issue in your fish example is that it redirects [stdout] of both [cmd] and [read], so if the latter prints anything, it'll be carried through the pipe.

But I don't think read should ever print anything (especially to stdout) in the normal case, so this should be fine.

*Edit*: If the exact semantics of `set var (cmd)` are needed, that can be achieved using `set var (printf '%s' $out)` and `set var_err (printf '%s' $err)`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would  be to redirect one of the streams to a file:

```
set tmpf (mktemp)
trap "rm $tmpf" EXIT

set var (cmd ^ $tmpf)
set var_err (cat $tmpf)
```